# Modify plugin "Auto Upload Images"

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to modify the code of the "Auto Upload Images" plugin of wordpress because it creates many images for me. For example, it creates images with different dimensions: The original image (image-original.jpg), image-original-150x150.jpg, image-original-200x125.jpg, image-original-200x200.jpg, image-original-200x200-150x150.jpg, image-original-200x200-200x125.jpg and I only want to save the image on my hosting(WP Uploads folder) with the dimensions that I configure in the plugin, in this case it would be "image-original-200x200.jpg".
What should I modify in the "Auto Upload Images" plugin?

Thank you very much and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: For questions about specific plugins I would recommend contacting the [plugin author](https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-upload-images/). I would also strongly discourage making any changes to the plugin itself because future updates will erase those changes. Lastly, this specific issue is probably a WordPress "feature" and not the plugin itself, where WordPress is trying to pre-generate all possible thumbnails that the theme has defined for images. I personally hate this feature, but core is not interested in removing it, last time I checked.